# .net: When i update the assembly version, it said: Could not load file or assembly. A strongly-named assembly is required

Tags: .net, serialization, version, signature, strongname

I have a assembly with C# code. And the version of this assembly is 1.0.0.0. This Assembly's information is serialized when i serialize the data of this assembly into binary. And then i update this assembly version into 4.0.0.0, **

> and i remove the signature

**. When i de-serialize the data of assembly, an exception occur, which is "Could not load file or assembly '[AssemblyName], Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=[TokenKey]' or one of its dependencies. A strongly-named assembly is required. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131044)".

How can i redirect my old version assembly to a new version assembly?
Does configuration assembly binding work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your config, add the following block ,

```
    <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
        <dependentAssembly>
            <assemblyIdentity name="yourAssembly" publicKeyToken="PKTokenOfYourAssembly"/>
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0" newVersion="4.0.0.0"/>
  </dependentAssembly>
</assemblyBinding>
```

Comment: hi, Furqan,
I have tried your suggestion, and when i run my application, i noticed that i removed the signature of the assembly, and by the message of msdn, it said that this element is no use to the non strong name assembly.
But i have some new idea, and tomorrow i will have a try, i will add my method into this question.
thank you very much.